# Why I receive this error about attribute in Python?

Tags: python, gtk, glade

I have a problem in a simple Glade/Gtk project, I have some objects like Button, Text inputs etc. I have a basic error, gi.repository.Gtk has no attribute 'builder'. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance

Here's the error that I receive (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RiN6.jpg)

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
import gi.repository
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        gladeFile = Gtk.builder
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file(gladeFile)
        self.builder.connect_signals(self)

        window = self.builder.get_object("button1")
        window.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main = Main()
    Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Do you have reason to suppose that `Gtk.builder` should exist?

Comment: Because the attribute is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

[Looks](https://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builder.html#creating-and-loading-the-glade-file) like your `gladeFile` should be a string containing the path to your glade file, e.g. `gladeFile = "example.glade"`.

Comment: Thanks Malan, just a distraction, I put a question here too fast